# AS 3.0 Zoom in-out

Tags: actionscript-3, zooming

i'm trying to make a zoom in and out of a movieclip when certain event is activated, anyone knows a way of doing this? i tried with mc.scaleX++ or mc.scaleY++ (i tried with mc.scaleX+10000) but nothing happened, any help?

Ok here is my code:

```
game_mc.substage_mc.rightHand.thread_mc.scaleX + 5;
game_mc.substage_mc.rightHand.thread_mc.scaleY + 5;
trace("scaleX: "+game_mc.substage_mc.rightHand.thread_mc.scaleX);
trace("scaleY: "+game_mc.substage_mc.rightHand.thread_mc.scaleY);
```

output: scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1

Comment: post your code, the scaleX scaleY methods are ok, there is probably something wrong

Comment: basically scale is the way to go. Put a trace and check your scale values. all should be ok.

Comment: There adrian, thanks! yeah i add something to the scaleX or Y factor and it is still 1... what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is assignment? ("+=" instead of "+")

```
game_mc.substage_mc.rightHand.thread_mc.scaleX += 5;
game_mc.substage_mc.rightHand.thread_mc.scaleY += 5;
```

Comment: Oh god... yeah i found it, it's not only that but i need to scale the rightHand instead of the thread. sorry for wasting your time!